# Is there a driver available for Thinkpad T540p fingerprint reader

Tags: drivers, lenovo, fingerprint-reader

The open source drivers supported by Ubuntu do not cover the reader included with this computer and the Launchpad project to supply such drivers appears to be dormant.

The reader is supplied by a company called Upek and supposedly there are Ubuntu drivers available somewhere but the [Lenovo's link](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion-Knowledge-Base/Configuring-Fingerprint-reader-in-Linux-Thinkpad-General/ta-p/522271) to [Upek](http://www.upek.com/support/downloads/linux/DownloadPSLinux.asp) does not show me any Linux drivers.